# python - importing folder make it stopped working

Tags: python, import, module, package

I am trying to import another project in my code to call functions :

my current projects :

```
Projects :
    project_one :
        __init__.py
        main.py
        src :
            writting:
                __init__.py
                code_one.py
                code_two.py
            reading :
                __init__.py
                code_three.py
    
    project_two :
        __init__.py
        main.py
        src :
            writting:
                __init__.py
                dev_one.py
                dev_two.py
            reading :
                __init__.py
                dev_three.py
```

I want to import dev_one.py in code_one.py.
So i did add the path to the directory and did my import :

```
 sys.path.append(path)
import project_two.src.writting as wrt
```

Note that dev_one.py import dev_two.py that way

```
from src.writting.dev_two import *
```

but now i have the following error :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src.writting.dev_two'
```

Comment: maybe you should add `__init__.py` in `src`. Or you should use `from dev_two import *`. Or you should use relative path with dot `from .dev_two import *`

Comment: or maybe you should add `sys.path.append(path_to_project_two)` and import without `project_two` - `import src.writting as wrt`. Do you import it in `main.py` in `project_two` ?